# how to change slide background colour using com.glide.slider.library.SliderLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using **com.glide.slider.library.SliderLayout** to create an image sliders in my app.
I'd like to change the background of the slider but I cannot. I tried add background colour in xml, or set background or background colour programmatically, none of them work.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Here is the code in xml:

```
<com.glide.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slider"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    custom:auto_cycle="true"
                    android:background="@color/sysWhite"/>
```

Here is the code to create slide:

```
val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
    requestOptions.centerInside()

    for (i in 0..3) {
        val sliderView = TextSliderView(this)
        // if you want show image only / without description text use DefaultSliderView instead

        // initialize SliderLayout
        sliderView
            .image(imageURL)
            .setRequestOption(requestOptions)
            .setProgressBarVisible(true)
            .setOnSliderClickListener(this)

        //add your extra information
        sliderView.bundle(Bundle())
        sliderView.bundle.putString("extra", selectedProduct?.name)
        slider.addSlider(sliderView)
    }

    slider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion)

    slider.findViewById<View>(R.id.slider).setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.sysWhite))

    slider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom)
    slider.setCustomAnimation(DescriptionAnimation())
    slider.setDuration(3000)
    slider.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
```

[image: screenshot for display]

Comment: instead of a static background, i recommend you extract colors from the image and set as the background instead - it results in a more pleasing UI https://medium.com/david-developer/extracting-colors-from-images-integrating-picasso-and-palette-b9ba45c9c418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In colors.xml file add the below attribute with your desired color:

```
<color name="glide_slider_background_color">#FFFFFF</color>
```